# iPhone is not rendering properly my website on slow networks

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I am experiencing strange iPhone behavior on my site, it doesn't display page correctly on slow (edge) networks however all works fine via Wi-Fi.

the page seems to be truncated but the footer and header of it are fine, it just looks like the container/content is missing or shortened (no constant sizes). Any ideas?

cheers,

/Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look for timeouts, particularly if you have Javascript loaders.

Comment: what you mean by loaders ? If ajax calls then nope, but lots of inhtml JS libs, would this be an issue ? I moved it into html as iphone wasn't loading js if it were external file on slow network.

Comment: OK, I have fixed that - have moved all under external lib and put html5 async=true on script, works like charm now :-) thanks